# the_content(); not showing in images.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problem getting the_content(); on image.php or attachment.php, the_content(); it's showing in single.php but no in imaage.php, I tried to edit the code but I got nothing,

```
<div class="content section-inner">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="posts">

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="content-inner">

                <div class="featured-media">

                    <?php $imageArray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, 'full', false); ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $imageArray[0] ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="attachment">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'post-image' ); ?></a>

                </div> <!-- /featured-media -->

                <div class="post-header">

                    <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo basename(get_attached_file( $post->ID )); ?></h2>

                    <div class="post-meta">

                        <span><?php _e('Uploaded', 'lingonberry'); echo ' '; the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span>

                        <span class="date-sep">/</span>

                        <span><?php _e('Width:', 'lingonberry'); echo ' ' . $imageArray[1] . ' px'; // 1 is the width ?></span>

                        <span class="date-sep">/</span>

                        <span><?php _e('Height:', 'lingonberry'); echo ' ' . $imageArray[2] . ' px'; // 2 is the height ?></span>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- /post-header -->

                <?php if ( ! empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) : ?>

                    <div class="post-content">

                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                    </div> <!-- /post-content -->

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- /content-inner -->

            <div class="post-nav">

                <?php
     /**
   * Grab the IDs of all the image attachments in a gallery so we can get the URL of     the     next adjacent image in a gallery,
    * or the first image (if we're looking at the last image in a gallery), or, in     a         gallery of one, just the link to that image file
   */
   $attachments = array_values( get_children( array( 'post_parent' =>     $post->post_parent,   'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment',         'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' ) ) );
   foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment ) :
    if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
    break;
 endforeach;

$l = $k - 1;
$k++;

if ( isset( $attachments[ $k ] ) ) :
     // get the URL of the next image attachment
    $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ $k ]->ID );
    $prev_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ $l ]->ID );
else :
    // or get the URL of the first image attachment
    $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ 0 ]->ID );
endif;
 ?>
                   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $prev_attachment_url ); ?>"         class="post-nav-older" rel="attachment"><?php _e('&laquo; Previous<span>     attachment</span>', 'lingonberry'); ?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $next_attachment_url ); ?>"     class="post-nav-newer" rel="attachment"><?php _e('Next<span> attachment</span> &raquo;', 'lingonberry'); ?></a>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div> <!-- /post-nav -->

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

            <p><?php _e("We couldn't find any posts that matched your query. Please try again.", "lingonberry"); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>    

    </div> <!-- /post -->

</div> <!-- /posts -->
```

I need help on this

Comment: You don't seem to be using `the_content()` function call.

Comment: I've added the <?php the_content(); ?> below the <?php the_excerpt(); ?> in my image.php on hosting, but seem it's doesn't work. Any help sir?

Comment: Can you adjust your code? Those lines are only executed when there is an excerpt because they are in an if-statement. Are you aware of that?

Comment: No I am not aware, that why I am asking the question. Can you give me the correct answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bit of a mystery but if it looks like this

```
<?php if ( ! empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) : ?>

      <div class="post-content">

               <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
               <?php the_content(); ?>

       </div> <!-- /post-content -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

the commands `the_excerpt()` and `the_content()` will only execute when there is an excerpt present. The if-statement says "if excerpt is not empty then execute the following code.

Try this:

```
      <div class="post-content">
<?php if ( ! empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) : ?>
               <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
               <?php the_content(); ?>

       </div> <!-- /post-content -->
```

There is a shorter way of writing this but this way it shows the change better.

Comment: I've tried your code above, but it's not work. The themes is free to download "Ligonberry" at wordpress themes, if you able to help me, I really thank you.

Comment: I think it is better for you to contact the theme creator.